# Explaining William Herschels Infrared Discovery

Tags: infrared-radiation

First post, and probably a very simple answer that I'm missing, but here goes. Herschel found that red light warmed a thermometer more than blue light, and consequently that the region beyond the red light (infrared) was even warmer. If blue light has a shorter wavelength, and therefore more energy, why does it not have the higher temperature on the thermometer?

I have a theory, he had painted the bottoms black so they were on some level a black body. At the room temperature, the spectral radiance curve was shifted way over into the longer wavelengths that infrared consists of. Is there any validity to this thoery?

Comment: What do you mean by "higher temperature on the thermometer"

Comment: What has to be the scale for equal amount of energy by square meter for every wavelength one want to measure its energy? One have to be sure he send the same amount of photons on the same area. Only under this conditions it is possible to find out which wavelength has more energy per photon.

Comment: There are some more difficulties. Thermometer could be transparent for some wavelengths. One have to use a black body and then measure the temperatures. But the same difficulty with the transparency. A ideal black body does not exist. But it shoud be satisfying to measure the visible and IR spectra. Always under the circumstanced from my first  comment

Comment: The reading of the temperature on thermometer was higher in the infrared region, for example it might have read 30 degrees Celsius in the violet area of the spectrum, but 35 degrees in the infrared. (These are not the actual values or deltas he measured, but the trend is identical)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blue light may have more energy **per photon** than red light, but the rate that energy is being deposited on a thermometer depends on the power spectrum of the particular light beam.  For example, a big bright red lightbulb can transfer a lot more energy per second than a tiny blue one, regardless of the wavelengths involved.

In Herschel's case, he was using sunlight, and sunlight has a well-characterized power spectrum:

[image: Sunlight spectrum]

The amount of power being transmitted in the red part of the spectrum (roughly 620-750 nm) is considerably higher than the amount of power being transmitted in the blue part of the spectrum (roughly 450-490 nm) - as you can see the power drops off sharply in the blue band.

You're right that the reason for the discrepancy is due to a blackbody spectrum, but it's not due to the blackbody spectrum of the **paper**, it's due to the blackbody spectrum of the **sun**.